# C# DataContract Attribute for Private Fields?

Tags: c#, datacontract

For a class marked with the attribute, [DataContract], does its private fields, which should be serialized, be marked as [DataMember]?

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Component
{

// [DataMember] is not needed since public fields get automatically serialized
public int number;

// do I need [DataMember] here?
private string characters;

// [DataMember] is required here, but I also need to include the 
// attribute [DataMember] in this class's definition
private complexType cT;
```

I'm reading [DataContractAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) correctly, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't look like you are reading the documentation correctly.

DataContracts are a way to publicly share information that is a little different than regular serialization.

From the documentation page you link:

> The DataMemberAttribute attribute must then be applied to each member of the data contract type to indicate that it is a data member, that is, it should be serialized.

But that only applies if you add the `[DataContract]` attribute like you did.

Comment: So, if my class is marked with the [DataContract] attribute, then I need to mark each Property or Field with the [DataMember] attribute if I want it to be serializable? If a Property or Field is not marked as [DataMember], then it won't be serialized?

Comment: what if my class's Properties are marked [DataMember], but not actual fields that the Properties set and get?

Comment: @Kevin That would work fine. It will use the properties' getters and setters to serialize and deserialize the data.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that the link says:

> By default, the DataContractSerializer infers the data contract and serializes all publicly visible types. All public read/write properties and fields of the type are serialized.

In my applications, I've found that *only* properties that include `[DataMember]` get serialized. Public properties with public getters/setters do not get serialized unless I specifically put `[Datamember]` on them.

---

To address your specific question, I would mark all 3 fields with `[DataMember]`, and `complexType` class should also be marked as a `[DataContract]`.

Comment: @rally25rs That's because you're probably adding the `[DataContract]` attribute. If you add the attribute to the class, then the members must also be attribued. But that line in the docs applies if you don't add the data contract attribute. The docs state that, but it is a little arcane.

Comment: @McKay : Ahhh, I see. Yeah, I definitely didn't get that subtle point from that document. Thanks for the info.