# Avoid serializing private datamembers during xml serialization

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a datacontract like below:

```
[DataContract]
class Person
{
    private string m_name;
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
     { get {return m_name;}
       set {m_name = value;}
     }
}
```

When xml serializer serializes this object, it is generating xml with private members like

```
<person><m_name>john</m_name></person>
```

How can I force the serializer to serialize only public properties.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate [C# DataContract Attribute for Private Fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883615/c-sharp-datacontract-attribute-for-private-fields)

Comment: DataContrac uses DataContractSerializer, not XmlSerializer, unless you've told it otherwise.  There is a difference.

Comment: As both `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` gave the expected answers, is it possible you actually decorated `m_name` with the `[DataMember]` attribute rather than `Name`?  Since Name doesn't appear in the XML you posted but m_name does....

Comment: Please post the code you use to serialize an object of the class.

Answer (score 2):

It’s strange that your private member writes to xml. I’ve tried to imitate your situation and serializer wrote only public field:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        private string m_name;
        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return m_name; }
            set { m_name = value; }
        }
    }
```

`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var person = new Person() {Name = "john"};

        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        var sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\person.xml");
        xs.Serialize(sw, person);
    }`

You can also read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: IMHO, I do not believe this answer addresses the OP's question based on the code he posted.  He's using `[DataContract]`, not `[Serializable]`, therefore DataContractSerializer will be used, which behaves differently than XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to Andark's answer, except I used the `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`.  This was done in VS 2012 targeting .NET 4.5.

Here's the test code:

```
using Sytem;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person myPerson = new Person() { Name = "Tim" };

            using (FileStream writer = new FileStream("Person.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {

                DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
                dcs.WriteObject(writer, myPerson);
            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    class Person
    {

        private string m_name;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return m_name;
            }
            set
            {
                m_name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following XML:

```
<Person xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Tim</Name>
<Person>
```

Which is what is expected.

It's important to note that the default serializer for `DataContract` is the `DataContractSerializer`, **not** `XmlSerializer`, and there are some differences.  Only members that are marked with `[DataMember]` should be serialized, and the access level (private, public, etc) is irrelevant - if you mark a private field or member with `[DataMember]`, it will be serialized.